# Create plugin pages in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, plugins

I am writing a Wordpress plugin for managing info about clients and projects for a company.

I have an admin menu called "Clients", which displays a simple table with all entries. If I have an "Edit" button for every table row, how would I link this button to another page where the data could be edited (passing the client id)? How does URL rewriting work here?

Sorry for asking such simple questions.. and thanks.

**Edit**:

How would I create this edit-page in the admin area, keeping the admin menu on the left, etc.? I have used this to add the submenu item:

```
    add_submenu_page( "my-plugin-menu", __('General settings').'|'.__('My Plugin'),
          __('General settings'), 1, "my-plugin-general", "my_plugin_admin_menu");

    /* Include admin page content. */
    function my_plugin_admin_menu()
    {
      global $wpdb;

      include 'admin/pages/admin_menu.php'; // Admin page content.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Where are the entries getting pulled in from? Is the posts table? or have you created your own table? Within the posts table you can pull in post_ID and use this.

Comment: I have created my own tables.

Comment: you would just need to append the client id to the end of the edit url. something like this: edit.php?clientid=1

Comment: Yes, thank you. Please read my edit to the question as well when you have time.

Comment: what sort of content does your table hold? It would probably be best to add a custom post type. This will add all of the necessary functionality for creating, editing and deleting posts.